# Running SonarQube behind Nginx proxy server in Centos?

Tags: nginx, proxy, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.2

After installing Nginx and letting SonarQube running in background, also configuring the conf.d file from nginx I am just getting a 500 error.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Running+SonarQube+behind+a+Proxy

What Am I missing?

Comment: To be able to help you, can you describe your configuration and show your configuration files for nginx and SonarQube ?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?